# A Wordpress site with more than one domain name / Parked domains

Tags: redirect, domain, domain-mapping

i have one WordPress blog/site and want to point/map more than one domain name hosted/parked on my server.

How do i do that ****without*** redirecting by .htaccess?*

Edit

Im configure the related setting in cpanel or plesk in parked domain but wordpress dont recognized them. I want to know why cant i confure thet easy as config it for first domain name? And also want to how do that?

Comment: I think this may be outside the scope of WPSE but you should be able to do it in CPanel or Plesk on the GUI end or park it with .htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a predefined constants that points to site URL.

(from [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29))

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME',    'http://example.com/wordpress');
```

Small example

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME',    'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: im config the configs about park domain in cpanel .... Then ... it means that i install it again for second url? In seperate folder? Or for first installation repeat it more times for each url address?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Multidomain enabler plugin for this purpose.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/multidomain-multitheme/

Plugin [Wordpress Multi domain screenshot here](http://www.ewallzsolutions.com/how-to-setup-multiple-domain-point-to-a-single-wordpress-installation/) (tested and worked!)